# how to create web pages in which network requests cannot be captured by browser's debugger

Tags: javascript, asp.net, security, applet

This doesn't involve coding. I am just curious on how to make a page like the one described below.
I came across a website where we can attend quiz/tests. 
I tried to debug the browser so that I can see if I could hack through the codes by getting the values that are getting passed in debugger.
But to my surprise the debugger is not coming up when I click **F12** in that page.

Somehow I opened debugger for that page and I clicked on the Network tab to capture requests that are sent.
But as I was proceeding through the test, not even one request is getting captured in the debugger but the answers are getting validated and scores are getting updated !! I was not even able to do **inspect element**
I guess its a java applet as i saw the below line in the the launch button

`flagPlayerCourse = true;launchApplet(secureSessionId,courseName, courseType,winParams, use508);disablePlayButton(1, 0);`
the url had `SinglePassUserCmd.cfm?sessionid=3xxxxx`

So my question is how can we create such a webpage in which the requests are not captured in the debugger!?  I would be happy if someone could tell me how do the same in asp.net. In which language can we develop such web pages!?

Comment: I think the trick was that the java runs outside the browser.  That's why java is often a security issue.  So once the java applet takes over, you would have to use a java debugger, not the browser debugger.

Comment: *"I came across a website.."*  The web is a big place.  What is the URL?

Comment: Moving to using an applet or other plugin doesn't make a page any less vulnerable to debugging or network sniffing, it just means the attacker has to use different (but no less readily available) tools. To choose a plugin rather than the browser as your development platform because you think it gives you any more security is a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Applets are completely different world. Its almost as good as running a .net application on your client machine.

What you see in the debugger are ajax requests and resources loading. If a site doesn't make them, you won't see any network requests in the browser.

That doesn't mean that you can't capture the data being send. You can always use a debugging proxy like [fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/) to see what traffic is going across. Ofcourse a secure site would secure their traffic over https.

Applets require a java plugin in your browser. There are similar plugins like Silverlight, flash/shockwave(swf) that too can make network requests.